# images inside uploads folder will return 404

Tags: uploads, htaccess, media

My images will not load . accessing anything inside the uploads folder returns 404 https://digitalzoomstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/image-1-1024x617.png

[image: file manager]

I am 99% sure I am not crazy and that I am accessing the direct path

I have deleted all plugins and caches that I know of and enabled default theme

I have set permissions to uploads/ folder to 755 and files inside to 644